# Can't "Allow" Box Drive extension for Mac OS Catalina

Tags: macos, box, macos-catalina, kernel-extension

I'm having troubles enabling the OS extension required for Box Drive to work.
I have installed Catalina (version 10.15.1 (19B88))
I would click "Allow", in System Prefs, as instructed; however, nothing happens and Box cannot start up.

Investigating in the Console I see the messages below:
[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fnqA.png)

Am I the only one to have this problem? Any ideas or suggestions to fix it?
Thanks,
Alessio

Comment: The issue seems to be reported in apple , might want to follow: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/118301